# How to create custom multi line autocomplete suggestion textbox in windows form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, autocomplete

I want to create multi line autocomplete suggestion in textbox in asp.net windows form like this image:

[image]

Now autocomplete is in single line suggest. How can i solve this issue.
Thank You

Comment: The big dropdown you are seeing with suggestions is not a textbox. It can be a div with other html elements such as span inside it with data populate in it. If you don't want to re-invent the wheel, you can search for JQuery plugins for autocomplete.... Using them will be easier then writing your own solution..

Comment: Thanks for your response this is not for web application  and this suggestion shows after text change in text box please see my image properly.

Comment: Your question is tagged `asp.net` that's why I suggested jQuery plugin. You need to remove the tags which are not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search I have found a solution on this tutorial:
[Autocomplete suggestion](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/365974/Autocomplete-Menu)